# IE div shorter than 20 px?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html

I can't seem to get my `<div>` height in IE (7) to be shorter than 20px:

```
<div style="background: green; height: 1px;">

</div>
```

Using the above code (both with and without html and body tags) the height of the div cannot seem to drop below a certain value (I think it is 20px).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:hidden;`.

Comment: np.  IE7 and lower can be funny with whitespace, line heights and font sizes - even though your div looks empty.

Comment: @aeq: If that worked for you, show Andy some love and accept his answer.

Comment: @Robusto: He needs to wait another 11 minutes before he can accept.  Looking forward to the love, though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Andy E's head is right. You seem to have empty space inside the div that is rendered as a space, which happens to have 20px height. So either hide the overflow or remove the whitespace.